# Access local network through one public IP

Tags: ssh, ip

I have a local network built up with 8 computers connected to switch. Main node has a public IP, so I can ssh it from external network. Is it possible to access other 7 nodes without assigning public IPs to them?(access them from the node that has public IP) I don't have access to the switch terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You can first ssh to the "public" node, then ssh to other nodes using local IPs.

Just a note: this question is not closely related to "Programming", so you may better post it to https://superuser.com/.

Comment: This doesn't work. I can't even ping local nodes form the "public" node.

Comment: That means you may have some problem with your local network setup or your "public" node. Have you checked routing table on the "public" node?